# Add file extension to PHP variable

Tags: php, sql

I need to add the file extension .zip to the following string:

```
$zipfilename  = $row_rsParentGal['gallery_name'];
```

Cant seem to get it right, the nearest I get is:

```
$zipfilename  = $row_rsParentGal['gallery_name'].zip;
```

but that just adds zip to the gallery_name and not the dot.

Many thanks
Tony

Comment: `$zipfilename  = $row_rsParentGal['gallery_name'] . '.zip';`

Comment: uhh.... learn php? any programming language, really...

Comment: Thats what I'm trying to do Nile!

Comment: learn as in read some guides about the "basics" of the language and programming. Not asks questions here about what you are trying to do. @Nile asked very nicely, but the attitude in your comment is not very welcome.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suppose you just want

```
$row_rsParentGal['gallery_name'] . ".zip";
```

This should concatenate the string ".zip" to the gallery name.

Comment: Don't forget that semicolon

Answer (score 0):

I had a function that may gives you the way

```
function replace_extension($filename, $new_extension) {
    $info = pathinfo($filename);
    return $info['filename'] . '.' . $new_extension;
}
```

or you can also use

```
function replace_extension($filename, $new_extension) {
    return preg_replace('/\..+$/', '.' . $new_extension, $filename);
}
```

Comment: Hey wat about my ans....Is it not working..??